# Make a navbar fill top space (not body margin:0;)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I just started building a simple navbar and realized there is some sort of default padding/margin at the top of the page. I tried using margin:0 & padding:0, but it only fixed the horizontal problem. I'm using chrome on OS X El Capitan.

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#navigation{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color:orange;
}

li{
    list-style-type:none;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">php stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about me</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Right click - inspect - check the `ul` element.

Comment: It was stupid of me to not expect that. I'm not used to using the inspect feature, I should do that more often. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#navigation {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: orange;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: this is a hack not a solution

Answer (score 0):

The ul tag's default padding/margin created my problem.